# Using a file instead of iteration data

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a collection where I need to loop over a Json file and run a certain number of request :

My actual pre-request script is this way :

```
pm.globals.set("jsonBody", JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.toObject()));
```

Instead of using iteration data (I don' want to use this option) I would like instead to specify a file inside my pre request script, how could I implement it?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to reference an external file like that in the app. If you're using the runner to iterate through the data, adding that file to the runner is the only way to do that, unless you use Newman to run the Collection but it would still need to be in the same accepted file format. What's the reason for not wanting to use `pm.iterationData.*`?

Comment: I am ruuning newman thourgh a shell script which means that I may use a data file as I may not depending on the team running the tests, therefore I prefer to no use -d option for newman run

Comment: pass the content of the file as an variable to newman

Comment: The way you would access that data would need to be all handled in the request themselves and also to be made to handle if the data isn't present. I think there's a whole bunch of stuff to think through here rather than just finding a way to use / not use a data file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a= Get-Content -raw .\1.csv
 newman run .\test.postman_collection.json -e .\test.postman_environment.json -k -r "cli,htmlextra" --env-var data=$a
```

The above example shows how to read a csv file and pass the content as variable "data" to newman